# Notation for iterated summation

Tags: notation

Is there a more compact way to write
$$
\sum_{i_1=0}^{N}
\sum_{i_2=0}^{N-i_1}
\sum_{i_3=0}^{N-i_1-i_2}
\cdots
\sum_{i_{K}=0}^{N-i_1-i_2-i_3-\ldots-i_{K-1}}
a_{i_1i_2i_3\ldots i_K}
$$
as something like
$$
\prod_{k=1}^K
\sum_{i_{k}=0}^{N-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}i_j}
a_{i_1i_2i_3\ldots i_k}
$$
for describing the iterations above instead of writing them down?

Comment: Something like $$\sum_{i_k\ge0,i_1+\ldots+i_K\le N} a_{i_1...i_K}$$?

Comment: It surely is more compact and describes it perfectly the operation (thanks btw), but I was expecting something more like an operator for the iteration of the sums. Do you think I should edit my question in order to make it more explicit?